# Composition OOP

Tags: python, oop

I have a class A that contains Class B in a strict sense of a 'has-a' relationship I.e. It makes sense for A to contain B. However there are only a couple of specific methods calls on B will affect A. For the most part modelling this will just lead to Class A having a method that calls Class B's methods with no real benefit and the downside of two function calls.

```
class A():

   b=B()

   __init__(self):
      self.a=[]

   def addToA(self,a):
      self.a.append(a)

   def addToB(a):
      # do something with self.a
      b.addToB(a)
```

What are people's thoughts on providing methods within A that is needed specifically when it alters B. however going to B directly otherwise:

```
z=A()
z.addToB(a)
z.b.methSpecificToB(x,y,z)
```

I feel I'm i'm breaking the encapsulation a little doing this however it makes more sense rather than simply providing superfluous methods..

Comment: Should `b` be `self.b` and `addToB()` take `self` as the first agument?

Comment: Hi Martin, b was meant to be a class attribute and should be shared among all instances. I have over simplified this code in the real code Class B is actually a library for a database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd generally prefer the indirection of calling the method on A to call the method on B because it protects A's clients from changes in the implementation of A and B.  For example, if later changes require that methodSpecificToB and some other method on B are called, I need only change A.addtoB, whereas if Z and other classes call B directly they all must be changed.

Ultimately it depends on the likelihood of B changing.  If that's never going to happen then exposing B is probably ok, but if it's a possibility then indirection is safer.

Comment: Thanks Snakecharmer yes that does make sense. I was leaning towards this.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with a `@property` decorator. When you set `A.B`, this will automatically set `B.A`.

```
class A:

    _b = None

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, b):
        self._b = b
        b.a = self

class B:

    a = None

foo = A()
bar = B()
foo.b = bar
bar.a == foo  # True
foo.b == bar  # True
```

What happens here is that when you set `foo.b`, it is saved as `foo._b`. (The underscore indicates a 'hidden' variable that is generally used for internal usage.) At the same time, `bar.a` is set to `foo`, enabling you to access `foo` from `bar`.

When trying to access `foo.b`, `foo._b` is returned instead. Since we set that to `bar` earlier, we also access `bar` from `foo`.

There are many tutorials on the Python properties. [This one](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) is kind'a OK.